# Using a function with more than one statement to render template string for an angular component throws value could not be determined statically

Tags: angular

I am trying to create my component template dynamically like so.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

function getTemplate() {
  let temp = "";
  for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    temp += "<div>Hi</div>";
  }
  return temp;
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: getTemplate(),
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";
}
```

The code runs in development mode but with lint error. And `ng build` fails with error `value could not be determined statically`

I saw other posts with this error but not related to a component. So creating this question.

What can be done to keep the dynamic template generation with a build success?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me this fails even in development mode

You need to define attributes, or method in the component, so that template can access them.

Here are different strategies to implement what you want to achieve.

I think using a service would be the cleanest solution

```js
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TemplateBuilderService {
  getTemplate(): string {
    let temp = '';
    for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
      temp += '<div>Hi</div>';
    }
    return temp;
  }
}

export class TemplateBuilder {
  static getTemplate(): string {
    let temp = '';
    for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
      temp += '<div>Hi</div>';
    }
    return temp;
  }
}

function getTemplate(): string {
  let temp = '';
  for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    temp += '<div>Hi</div>';
  }
  return temp;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <section>
      {{ templateBuilderService.getTemplate() }}
    </section>
    <section>
      {{ TemplateBuilderStatic.getTemplate() }}
    </section>
    <section>
      {{ getTemplate }}
    </section>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public TemplateBuilderStatic = TemplateBuilder;
  public getTemplate = getTemplate();

  constructor(public templateBuilderService: TemplateBuilderService) {}
}
```